# How to identify double click in SELECT element with multiple

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a SELECT element with the MULTIPLE attribute.  When double-clicking on an option in the list, I want to **take an action based on the option being clicked**.

I understand that the OPTION element doesn't handle the `ondblclick` event.  If I handle the `dblclick` event of the SELECT element, is there some way I can identify which option was double-clicked?

```
<select size="4" name="MySelect" multiple="multiple" ondblclick="myFunction();">
    <option ... />
    ...
</select>
```

Preferably cross-browser, but IE only would do.

**EDIT**

I obviously wasn't clear enough.  What I need to do is identify **which option was double-clicked** from within the event handler (or that the double-click was in an area of the SELECT element without an option).  Looking for `selectedIndex` won't do as the SELECT element has the MULTIPLE attribute: if the user holds <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when double-clicking, more than one item will be selected: I only want the option that was actually double-clicked.

Comment: "but IE only would do" - well, if it works in IE it is cross-browser ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('selectID').ondblclick = function(){
    alert(this.selectedIndex);
    // or alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
};
```

If you double click on an item, you select it, so you can use this.selectedIndex.

Comment: No, the select allows multiple selection.  this.selectedIndex will give the index of the *first* selected option, not necessarily the one that was double-clicked.

Comment: Use `selectedOptions` which returns an `HTMLCollection` you can loop/iterate through just like an array. `selectedIndex` will be the first, or `-1` if none.

Comment: how to get selectedIndex from option tag

Answer (score 5):

```
<select onDblClick="alert(this.value)">  
   <option>Barney</option>
   <option>Ted</option>
   <option>Marshall</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you attach the event on the options? It works fine here (tested with and without jquery in Firefox 3.6).

```
<select size="4" name="MySelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>aoeu</option>
    <option>ieao</option>
    <option>.yao</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("option").bind("dblclick", function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I believe he **needs** it work with IE, firefox is the optional piece.

Comment: I tried attaching an event (not using jquery as above), and it didn't work with IE :(  As Nick Craver said, IE is mandatory, cross-browser is nice-to-have (a corporate environment that is still using IE6!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Following what Harmen wrote .. the following will alert the value of the doubleclicked option .. (cross browser)

```
document.getElementById('selectID').ondblclick = function(e){
    var evt = window.event || e;
    var elem = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
    alert(elem.value);
};​
```

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work in IE (8): http://jsfiddle.net/sorin_postelnicu/44Gum/embedded/

Comment: Actually it seems to be working after manually adding value attributes. Apparently, in the case of missing value attributes, FF assumes that the value is the same as the label, whereas IE assumes that the value is empty. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sorin_postelnicu/44Gum/1/embedded/

Comment: Nope, it's not working. In case of multiple selections (with CTRL+doubleclick), the displayed value is the value of the first selected option in the list.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the selected value in a new form, then use this combination:
with either onclick or dblclick:

```
    <form name="Editcust" action="select_cust_process.php" method="post">
    <select name="mydropdownEC"  onMouseOver="this.size=10;" onclick='this.form.submit()'>
    <option ... />
     ...
    </select>        
    <br /><input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Select&nbsp;&nbsp;"/> 
    </form>
```

and inside select_cust_process.php I have:

```
    $TBLrow = $_POST['mydropdownEC'];
    echo $TBLrow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you wrap it with a `<div/>`? something like this

HTML:

```
<select>
   <option value="x">
      Option text goes here
      <div class="option-dbclickable" style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; z-index:999;"></div>
   </option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.option-dbclickable').ondblclick = function(){
   alert(this.parentNode.value);
};
```

I haven't tested it but it theoretically might work. I used this trick on many form elements but unfortunately not a multiple select for double click.

Comment: Tried to wrap it like this, but the <div> within <option> seems to be ignored

Comment: @SebastianReimer have you tried `event.preventDefault()` on `option` tag's click event?